# Maven - Configurando a MainClass

Tags: java, maven, jar

**Problema:**

Quando crio um `JAR` pelo `eclipse` ele funciona tranquilamente, mas estou tentando aproveitar o `JAR` que o `Maven` está criando e percebi que ele não executa, pois minha classe `main` não esta no `Manifest`.

---

Use essa configuração no `POM.XML` para informar a minha classe `Main`:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>ClasseMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

---

Quando uso o `mvn install` recebo:

```
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.app:ClasseMain:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin is missing. @ line 52, column 12
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your build.
[WARNING] 
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed projects.
[WARNING]
```

Pelo que entendi esse aviso e referente ao código que postei acima, mas não consigo encontrar uma solução para o aviso desaparecer. E mesmo informando onde está classe `Main` o `JAR` não entra em execução.

---

**Dúvida**

Se o código que estou informando no `POM.XML` está incorreto para informar a classe `Main` qual é o certo?
Como desaparecer com o `WARNING` que aparece sempre que faço um `mvn install`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Caso você **não tenha** dependências externas de outros JARs basta usar o maven-jar-plugin e colocar a referencia completa para sua classe que possui o método `public static void mais(String[] args)` como no exemplo abaixo.

```
<build>
    <finalName>meu_main</finalName>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>qualquer.que.seja.seu.pacote.ClasseMain</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Execute :

```
mvn install package
java -jar build/meu_main.jar
```

Caso ocorra o erro `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` ou `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` é porque existe dependência externa.

Esta abordagem citada acima não funciona se sua aplicação depender de um JAR externo tal como o Log4J.jar, por exemplo. Uma das alternativas para resolver este tipo de problema é usar o plugin `maven-assembly-plugin` que expande as dependências declaradas no POM.xml como classes e depois agrupa tudo no JAR resultante. Assim você fica com todas as classes e recursos (imagens, arquivos de propriedade, etc) disponíveis no JAR final gerado. Neste caso você se livra dos erros `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` ou `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException`

**Exemplo com** `maven-assembly-plugin`

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <archive>
            <manifest>
                <mainClass>qualquer.que.seja.seu.pacote.ClasseMain</mainClass>
            </manifest>
        </archive>
        <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
        </descriptorRefs>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Neste caso você deve invocar o build do JAR assim:

```
mvm assembly:assembly
```

Para achar o Jar gerado execute (no MAC OS ou Linux):

```
ls target/*jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

E para executar execute (no MAC OS ou Linux) :

```
java -jar target/*jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Comment: Interessante. Percebi que mvn `package` ou `install` geram um `JAR` na pasta `target`. Se usar `.` ou `/` nessa linha   `<mainClass>com.aplication.ClasseMain</mainClass>` também não tem influência, o `JAR` gerado funciona. O estranho é que meus `JARs` que uso como dependência não estão dentro do `JAR` gerado. Como coloca-los lá usando `Maven`?

Comment: oi @EduardoBentoRochaJunior respondi com um exemplo do `maven-assembly-plugin`

Comment: Outra alternativa é usar o `maven-dependency-plugin` para copiar os arquivos pro lugar desejado.

Comment: O `maven-assembly-plugin` funciona, porém ele desempacota as dependência e inclui ao `JAR`. O processo que preciso fazer é simplesmente adicionar o `.jar` das dependências o eclipse faz isso. Esse `maven-dependency-plugin` faz isso? (vou testar)

Comment: use o maven-dependency-plugin então

Comment: João Paraná ou @Eduardobrj, sabem como rodar o `maven-dependency-plugin` direto pela interface do eclipse ao invés de usar linha de comando para fazer `mvn assembly:assembly`?

Comment: @Math, posso está falando besteira, usando `mvn clean` e depois `mvn install`, automaticamente o ele chama o `maven-dependency-plugin`. Para usar direto pela interface do eclipse, `Botão direito no projeto` > `Run` > `Depois tem as opções mvn` e se precisar personalizar vá `Run Configurations`.

Answer (score 1):

Sua classe main deveria ser declarado desta forma:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4</version>
    <configuration>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <mainClass>com.exemplo.system.App</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

E o comando a ser usado seria o `mvn package`